# How to keep databases changes on access database on a portable executable created with Enigma Virtual Box

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, virtualbox, desktop-application

I am working on a desktop project with c# with Access database. Now I have finished my project and I need to have an executable file contains all the components and ddls and my access database of my project.
In other words, I want an executable file runs portable.
Fortunately I was able to create this portable executable file by [Enigma Virtual Box](http://enigmaprotector.com) and my project works fine on all windows without any installed.

But there is a problem that i could not solved it. when i inserted or updated or deleted any record in access database every thing is fine. but when i close my application and run again Everything is back to normal.

In other words, when I run the application previous database copied again in executable file.

In this case one can not help? Or there are other solutions for the portable executable file?

Comment: You will have to save your access database somewhere in order for it to be persisted... You do not want to write over your program executable with the new database every time...

Comment: @Milney yes i know it but how?

Comment: @Milney, unless virtual box save its state after software finished working. That's the question to one who works with exactly same thing, but as here is no tag for it yet, OP best bet is to read manual or contact tool manufacturer.

Comment: Don't use that product, it looks like it is a 'sandbox' style application, so does this on purpose... You can just look into MSBuild rules to compile your whole application into one file, and place the access database somewhere on the file system on first run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After any change of data base you must rebuild exe file, you can't save changes in exe file. So dont pack database.